# Is there a way to define environment variables for already existing containers in EKS clusters?

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-ecs, amazon-eks

I know that you can use **Task Definitions** to define *environment variables* for **ECS** containers, I'm just wondering if you can use the same method for **EKS**, or there is another way?

 Sorry I'm new to AWS and Kubernetes and all of that.

Comment: You can think of a kubernetes `Deployment` or `Statefulset` as the equivalent of an ECS task definition.

Comment: @jordanm thank you, I need to study it better but at least I have a direction